# List of all available keys that can override intelliJ settings from idea.properties file

Tags: intellij-idea, properties, settings

Like many of us I want to be able to init my dev configuration through a conf file or simply share it with my team.

I know that the idea.properties file allows to override properties.

But the problem is that I can't find any docs with an exhaustive list of all keys that can be used to override intelliJ settings preferences like build tools parameters etc ...

I only find some of those keys like in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties ...

I wonder if such a list even exists ?

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-idea-properties.html and https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/bin/idea.properties for more examples

Answer (score 0):

The idea.properties file does not allow to manage all settings key but just a few ones.

I could get what I wanted storing my conf in the [dedicated dir](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository) and using [shared repo](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) or just [exporting/importing settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings) to keep all team members synced.